# How to pass variables from one stage to another in release pipeline of azure devops?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I wanted to pass a variable from one stage to another in release pipeline of azure devops is there any way to do it?
I'm trying to run the second stage only if the first stage returns true/1 then deploy the second one, else skip the second continue with third. Can I make use of deployment gates for the same? please let me know.

[image: Reference image]

I already tried using "##vso[task.setvariable variable=run]true" method this only worked for build pipeline stages but not for release.

Comment: Can you use deployment gates? It depends on how the stage result is calculated. Can you explain how a stage determines true or false? If it's just stage success you can use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages

Comment: Checked, deployment gates cannot be used in this case need some different  approach.

Comment: We don't know what the case is - i.e. what is the logic that decides the boolean?

Comment: It can be as simple as a powershell scrip returning true or 1.